# How to remove one cluster from quartz cluster

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I have quartz clustered environment with 5 nodes, I am not sure how quartz scheduler load balance the jobs, mostly I am seeing all jobs does not get scattered properly. Could you please let me know is there a way to easily remove one node from quartz cluster so jobs will not run from that cluster or if some big job is running no other jobs should kick off from that cluster, In short can we pause the quartz jobs in one cluster?I use JDBCStore.
Pls find my quartz properties below. My quartz version is 2.2.0

```
        <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">myscheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
            </prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.test.jndiURL">java:test</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource">${datasource.name}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">myschema.QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class">org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the clustering capatibilties of quartz you should be able to switch down one node without problems. All quartz schedulars check the database if the other nodes are active and their last up-timestamp. If you check your quartz-config you would realize there is an (internal) quartz-job running which is updating one of the quartz tables frequently.

My answer is very generall because more information about your system environment and the configuration would be needed for a proper answer. 
What do you mean by "all jobs does not get scattered properly"?

Comment: What I mean Quartz does not look into load on a node before starting the job, I searched a tables of Quartz and did not see any table which keep track of active nodes.

Comment: Please add more information about your system, quartz version, configuration, database, ...

Comment: My System has 5 Jboss 5.1 app server, data is oracle and quartz version is 2.2.0, I am adding quartz properties to main comment as i do not have enough characters here.